Using plt.show() in python with fiure cleared
I runned my code on VSCode.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
  
# create and show first figure  
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])  
plt.show()  
  
# modifies the graph and displays it again        
plt.title('Updated Plot') 
plt.show() 
  
# clears the current drawing     
plt.clf()  
  
# creates and displays a second graphic  
plt.plot([4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3])  
plt.show()

The outputs are figures I upload.
By the way, the other weird thing is that the scale on the coordinate axis in the third figure is reversed.
Who can tell me a way to avoid it?
[figure1](https://i.sstatic.net/16OxA.png)
figure2
figure3
The outputs are on the details.

what exactly are you trying to do? its not very clear to me
